# Issue in starting Node App on Windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, express, npm

I am using windows 7 and I have installed node.js and express. 
After I create a project using express  using the command below

```
> express projectName
```

A new project is created and after that to install dependencies I do

```
> npm install
```

All works good so far. but when I try to start the application

```
> npm start
```

Below is the issue I get in the npm-debug.log  file. Please suggest whats wrong here. **I have tried many other threads but solution found there work for me.**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.33
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info prestart NodeTestApp@0.0.0
7 info start NodeTestApp@0.0.0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info NodeTestApp@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
10 error NodeTestApp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
10 error spawn ENOENT
11 error Failed at the NodeTestApp@0.0.0 start script.
11 error This is most likely a problem with the NodeTestApp package,
11 error not with npm itself.
11 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
11 error     node ./bin/www
11 error You can get their info via:
11 error     npm owner ls NodeTestApp
11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
12 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error cwd C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\NodeTestApp
15 error node -v v0.10.33
16 error npm -v 1.4.28
17 error syscall spawn
18 error code ELIFECYCLE
19 error errno ENOENT
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: An express generated app should be calling `./bin/www` and not `app.js`.  Did you change this in your `package.json`?  If feels like you might be omitting information or skipping steps you took.

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis yes its ./bin/www . I changed it to app.js because I was following a tutorial. Originally it was ./bin/www and I updated the result above when I did > npm start . It almost seems identical.

Answer (score 0):

[`child_process.spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) returns `ENOENT` when it can't find the requested executable; in this case, node.exe.  Looking closely at the log, we can see that `npm start` is attempting to run `node app.js`.

Is node on your `PATH`?  What happens if you just type `node app.js` on the command line?

Comment: When I type only node app.js it do nothing and control returns again to the same place. Result Below


C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\airline2>node app.js <br> 

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\airline2>

Comment: and Yes node.js is in my PATH variables

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It's working for me on Windows 7 32 bit node.js

Create new blank folder for your project.Go to your project folder and create manually **npm** folder (don't use command line).

Then try again create new project.

Hope this help.